Is it a problem to have multiple MeterProviders in a single Windows Service process?
I have a Windows Service which is currently configured to spawn 144 threads to process its workload. Each thread has one Worker class instance and each Worker class maintains 3 instances of our FileTrace classes. (We're moving files from point to point.) All told we have 432 FileTrace classes. We recently inserted Open Telemetry into the FileTrace class. As such -
The FileTrace class (each of 432 instances) maintains instance variable references to a MeterProvider, a Meter and a Counter:
    private MeterProvider m_meterProvider;
    private Meter m_meterFileTrace;
    private Counter<int> m_counterFileTrace = null;

These are instantiated when the class is initialized and these references are held for the lifetime of the class, which is held for the duration of the Service.
    m_meterProvider = TelemetryUtils.GetMeterProvider("REXBridge", "8.1", meterNames, false, true);
    m_meterFileTrace = new Meter("rater8.rex.filetrace");
    m_counterFileTrace = m_meterFileTrace.CreateCounter<int>(Counter);

So we've got a lot of these loaded, but it's not like these are being created / re-allocated / re-created during the lifespan of the service.
When it comes time to export the metric, here's how it's done:
   beginTags = DateTime.UtcNow;
   
   KeyValuePair<string, object>[] tags = new KeyValuePair<string, object>[13];
   tags[0] = (new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TenantId", TenantId));
   << snip >>
   tags[12] = (new KeyValuePair<string, object>("PipelineId", m_PipelineId));

   endTags = DateTime.UtcNow;

   m_counterFileTrace.Add(1, tags);

   endExport = DateTime.UtcNow;

Note the capturing of the timestamps. After this block executes, these are saved to the database.
Everything works. However, with telemetry exporting enabled, the service slows to a crawl, basically running at half speed.
I inserted secondary timing code in there to capture how long it takes to export the telemetry data. (Instrumentation for the performance of my instrumentation.) The following graph is based on a query which groups telemetry exports by second. For each second, I'm capturing the max time recorded for the export of the telemetry which began on that second. Here's what it looks like.
About half of the telemetry export operations are very fast, sometimes they don't even reach a single millisecond. But other times we're looking at around half a second. And we see timings of 1 second, 2 seconds and even 2.5 seconds. This is concerning. (I am using Batch - not Simple - export.)

Is there anything in the code or in the concurrency pattern described above to indicate that I'm not setting this up properly for optimal performance? Thanks for your advice!
EDIT: Additional debugging steps:
We cut out the attributes and modified the export of the counter to -
m_counterFileTrace.Add(1);

We changed the Telemetry instance reference variables to static so these are only initialized once (under lock coverage) with the creation of the first FileTrace class instance. All 432 instances of FileTrace are utilizing the same instance of Counter when they execute the export of the Counter.
Neither of these adjustments had any effect. The application continued operating properly. The Telemetry data was exported and seen at the DataDog side. However the application continues to slow down dramatically when we have the export of Telemetry enabled.

"Is there anything in the code or in the concurrency pattern described above" - Yes: you say you're creating 144 threads - but unless your computer has 144 CPU cores then all those threads are just getting-in-the-way. Only use as many threads as you have CPU cores and use nonblocking IO (aka "async APIs") so you don't have any blocked threads.

Just to confirm, those MeterProvider types are from OpenTelemetry, right?

You seem to be using DateTime.UtcNow for measuring time; don't do that: it's unhelpfully imprecise. Use Stopwatch instead.

@Dai Empirically we see that we get more throughput with the additional threads. The fact that we're doing a lot of IO may be helping us to get utility out of more threads than we have processors. Yes, the MeterProvider is from Open Telemetry. Point taken regarding the timestamping. However the impact of OT is so gross that there's no doubt it's happening. The service literally runs at half speed when OT is enabled.

I'm going to have to disagree slightly with Dai's first comment. While 144 threads is indeed on the heavy side (you might consider lowering the memory footprint by lowering the default stack size for those threads), you should not have more active threads on average than you have cores - if most threads are typically waiting on some event, for example, it's fine.

"Empirically we see that we get more throughput with the additional threads." - I don't doubt that, but when that's happening it means you've got a thread-starvation problem - spamming 144+ threads is just papering over the problem.

@Dai We have no problem unless we enable the interface with Open Telemetry. Those same classes have database connections. Writing to the database doesn't slow my processing down to half speed. Writing to a log file doesn't slow it down to half speed. Why should broadcasting to a memory location slow it down like that? Nothing spikes when I turn on Telemetry. Yet the service slows down to half speed. The question is, does this tie back to the threading model or is there some other root cause here?

@YossiG. Have you used your profiler?

@Dai Not yet. We just became aware of the problem yesterday. So we have to dig into this. I was wondering if anyone had experienced this before, a slowdown when using OTel with heavy concurrency. We do have 432 MeterProviders, Meters and Counters instantiated, although as you and others have pointed out, they're not all active simultaneously. Some resource is being bottlenecked, we'll have to dig in and find out what it is.

@YossiG. The good news is that you can run the profiler against your production system without incurring any outage or downtime - just attach, measure, detach. You also might want to consider making an ETW trace as well, which can help track-down issues with unexpected root-causes elsewhere in the system.

@YossiG. When you say "saved to the database" - that got me wondering if you might be having some DB lock-contention going on...

@Dai The save to the database is something we inserted AFTER observing the dramatic slowdown in processing. That cannot be root cause.
